# How to get sum of the XML repeated element values from a list in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have XML data source which is providing xpath list of `<policyRiders>`. In the `<policyRiders>` list there is xpath called `<sumInsuredAmount>` which is repeated with `<policyRiders>` xpath list. I want to take sum of all `<sumInsuredAmount>`.

[image: XML Data Source]

Currently I am using a table and variable declaration generate the .

**This is the source subDataset:**

```
<subDataset name="Dataset2">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/AUWrite/cacheDB/RetrievePolicyListResponse/policy/RetrievePolicyRiderListResponse/RLSPolicy/policyRiders]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="sumInsuredAmount" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="sumInsuredAmount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sumInsuredAmount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="ridersSumInsuredAmount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{sumInsuredAmount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
</subDataset>
```

This is the Table source code:

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="20" y="40" width="129" height="10">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
    </reportElement>
    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
        <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset2">
            <datasetParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="XML_INPUT_STREAM">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_INPUT_STREAM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="XML_FILE">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_FILE}]]>/datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.xml.source">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{net.sf.jasperreports.xml.source}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="XML_DATE_PATTERN">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATE_PATTERN}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="XML_NUMBER_PATTERN">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_NUMBER_PATTERN}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="XML_LOCALE">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_LOCALE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="XML_TIME_ZONE">
                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_TIME_ZONE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:column width="138">
            <jr:detailCell height="24">
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="138" height="24" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ridersSumInsuredAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
        </jr:column>
    </jr:table>
</componentElement>
```

Actual result:

[image: **Actual result**]

Actual result totalling the sum and displaying 200000,100000 and repeating the list element.

It shouldn't repeatable since total sumInsuredAmount should generate from one field.

sumInsuredAmount total shoud be 150000 which is come from addition of 100000 and 50000.

Expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: You are using table wrong. You can use group footer or table footer for showing aggregate data (total sum)

Comment: Thanks @AlexK i could be able to get the sum insured total without repeated rows by using table footer.